# Scatterplot plot multiple groups of points with different colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, paint, scatter-plot

I want to paint different color the key of diccionary, how can i get this?

```
colors: {"Hardcover": "red", "Kindle Edition":"green", "Paperback":"blue", "ebook":"purple", "Unknown Binding":"black", "Boxed Set - Hardcover":"yellow"}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))

for key, value in colors.items():
         ax.scatter(data["Type"], data["Price"], c=value, label=key)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Imagen]

Comment: Your image upload failed, can you fix?

Comment: Hello Tom, I am trying fix the mistake but I cant. The plot is it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6emz0.png

Comment: `ax.scatter(data["Type"], data["Price"], ...)` will plot the same data over and over again. Thus, the scatterplots will be layered exactly on top of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to iterate over the colours. You can just pass it in as a Series.

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['Hardcover', 'Kindle Edition', 'Paperback'], 'Price': [1,2,3]})
colors = {'Hardcover': 'red', 'Kindle Edition':'green', 'Paperback':'blue'}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))

scatter_colors = data['Type'].map(colors)
ax.scatter(data['Type'], data['Price'], c=scatter_colors)

print(scatter_colors)
plt.show()
```

I would argue that a legend is not required in your case. If you really want to have it, I think the only way might be to iterate over the 'Types'
[image]

Edited since the OP wants the legend:
Replace the `scatter_colors` and `ax.scatter` lines from the code block above with this:

```py
for book_type in data['Type'].unique():
    data_subset = data[data['Type'] == book_type].copy()
    ax.scatter(data_subset['Type'], data_subset['Price'], color=colors[book_type], label=book_type)
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, it is exactly that I need. But I have to add the legend. How can I get it?

Comment: Edited to show this now. I still feel that it is kind of pointless because the x tick label is saying the same thing, but if you wish...

Comment: Thanks you very much!!